# How to add executable bash script on ubuntu startup

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, scripts, startup

I have created a executable bash script (using chmod +x) for monitoring my system and it works perfectly with out any error. Now i want to add this script on my start up in order to executing the script on every reboot. I have saved this executable file in my documents folder like this

```
/home/user/Documents/file.sh
```

For running this script on start up; from dash i searched and selected "Startup Applications" and added the details and location of the script and done a fresh reboot. But even after a fresh reboot the script is not working but the script is executing when i do it with terminal (eg `./file.sh`). What changes should i make it to run my script on start up. If it helps this is the attribute of my script

```
-rwxrwxr-x ;using ls -l
```

Answer (score 11):

One more option is schedule a job at boot time

```
crontab -e
```

Choose an editor to open the cron job file.
Append the following with your script name

```
@reboot path/to/script.sh
```

In your case

```
crontab -e

@reboot /home/user/Documents/file.sh
```

Make sure the script has executable permission.

Comment: Please clarify which file you mean. It's unclear, although your answer might be 100% right... You could eventually also give a valid example.

Answer (score 2):

So I have succesfully run the script using my method itself (System > Preferences > Startup Applications). These are the changes I made to my script.

Added this line at the top of my script

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Then made executable using this command

```
chmod u+x file.sh
```

rebooted the system

Comment: I did all of these without success.  The script just does not execute on startup.  Anything else you did? (My script automatically opens all the windows I use every day)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what [Eka](https://askubuntu.com/users/158636/eka) says, make sure your `.desktop` file, in `~/.config/autostart/`, contains the following lines:

```
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

This did the trick to me.